# How to solve undeclared query parameters error in biqquery?

Tags: google-bigquery

```
SELECT
  @run_date,
  Country_PG,
  SUM(Weighted_Revenue) AS Weighted_Pipe
FROM
  `revenue.data`
GROUP BY
  1,2
```

When I run this query I am getting an undeclared query error for `@run_date`.

How do I solve this error?

For your information: this is a scheduled query.

Comment: Have you declared and set the  variable **run_date**  with the statements _DECLARE_ and _SET_ respectively ?

Comment: @AlexandreMoraes, `@run_date` is a query parameter passed in by Scheduled Query framework, not a scripting variable.

Answer (score 2):

When you are running the query manually, it is expected to fail if `@run_date` is not defined (by you).

When you are running it as scheduled query, based on [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries#configuration_options) `@run_date` should be passed in by BigQuery, if you got error telling `@run_date` is not defined, create a bug to BigQuery [here](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).

Answer (score 2):

When you attempt to test a scheduled query with either the parameter @run_date or @run_time in the UI it will return the error: "Undeclared query parameters"

However, when run as part of a backfill or at the scheduled time it will work correctly.

This is a bit ugly from a UI standpoint, but in order to test the scheduled query you should use the BQ command line as stated in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries#setting_up_a_scheduled_query)

Comment: $ bq query --nouse_legacy_sql "select DATE(@run_date)"

<snip>
Query parameter 'run_date' not found at [1:13]

Comment: This answer is correct. If you are using `@run_date` as a parameter, probably you are dealing with Scheduled Queries. If so, the solution to this error when writing the SQL query is just to ignore it.